# maximization of the product of two quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am trying to find $x$ to maximize the product of two quadratic forms:

$$\max\limits_{x} (x'Ax \cdot x'Bx)  $$

In my case, both of the matrices A and B are positive definite. It seems that a common problem is to maximize the *quotient* of two quadratic forms, e.g. $$\max\limits_{x}\frac{x'Ax}{x'Bx} $$ by substituting $B = M'M$ and $y = Mx$, changing the $x$'s to $y$'s, and then solving $$\max\limits_{y} \frac{y'M^{-1} A M^{-1} y} {y'y} $$ which is just the largest eigenvector of $ M^{-1} A M^{-1}$. Can a similar approach be used for the *product* of two quadratic forms as above? I can't figure out how to do it, but I don't understand exactly why it should be different. I can get close to the answer by approximating $$ x'Bx \approx \frac{1}{x'B^{-1}x}   $$ and taking the largest eigenvector of $M A M$ instead of $ M^{-1} A M^{-1}$, but that approximation is accurate only if $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$, and I don't fully understand the implications of that. Can anyone help me see what I'm missing here? Ideally, I'm hoping there is a way to solve this using efficient matrix operations instead of an iterative method, but if there isn't, I'd like to be able to understand why.

Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention, this is under the constraint $x’x = 1$

Comment: no answer unless $x$ is, in some way, bounded. A popular choice would be $x'x=1$

Comment: The problem you suggested is unbounded. Is it possible that your problem is a minimization instead of a maximization? or maybe that the matrices are negative definite?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I had omitted that - I edited the question to include the constraint $x'x=1$

Comment: I never figured out the answer to this question, but I found another way to solve the problem. Thanks for your comments!